# Parse elements from XML column in SQL Server

Tags: xml, select

`A column in the table I am querying if of type xml. I want to get only the values for the tags: //activity oldGUID. //Here is the structure of the xml`

```
<otherData>
  <timeRecord>
    <employee GUID="b8e8c500-6b20-423a-bfb3-4af96f683b93" />
    <start oldDate="2018-01-02T04:30:00">
      <activity oldGUID="8e0a6271-d487-4eb8-b97f-3bca8ddb4b2f" />
      <site oldGUID="534a8176-bb48-43a3-b5f9-7d6022446131" />
    </start>
    <stop oldDate="2018-01-02T04:30:00">
      <activity oldGUID="3e7ce3dd-ca59-4878-840b-fca2abb43411" />
      <site oldGUID="534a8176-bb48-43a3-b5f9-7d6022446131" />
    </stop>
    <shift oldGUID="" />
    <payCode oldGUID="" />
    <comments />
  </timeRecord>
</otherData>
```

`This is what I wrote:`

```
select
    s.EventGUID,
    m.c.value('@employee GUID[1]', 'varchar(max)')as id 
    from [dbo].[tb_EventLog] as s 
    outer apply s.otherData.nodes('/otherData/timeRecord') as m(c)
```

If I were to replace the variable with something that doesnt have space like comments, the query works fine. This xml is coming from vendorDB and not much I can do about how the tags are spaced

Comment: `activity` is an element (or tag), `oldGUID` is an attribute. Xpath: `//activity/@oldGUID`. I would try `m.c.value('//employee/@GUID', 'varchar(max)')as id`

Comment: Thanks can you show me how to write this query.

Comment: The same you have but replace the m.c... line with the one above.

Comment: I get this error: Msg 2389, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
XQuery [dbo.tb_EventLog.OtherData.value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'

Comment: You can upvote the accepted answer too if you wish :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query could be

```
select
s.EventGUID,
m.c.value('(./employee/@GUID)[1]', 'varchar(max)')as id 
from [dbo].[tb_EventLog] as s 
CROSS APPLY s.otherData.nodes('/otherData/timeRecord') as m(c)
```

For activity it could be

```
select
s.EventGUID,
m.c.value('(./start/activity/@oldGUID)[1]', 'varchar(max)')as id 
from [dbo].[tb_EventLog] as s 
CROSS APPLY s.otherData.nodes('/otherData/timeRecord') as m(c)
```

Comment: Yayyyy it works well. However I tweaked it so that I can get activity oldGUID it returns null. See my code  select
s.EventGUID,
m.c.value('(./activity/@oldGUID)[1]', 'varchar(max)')as id 
from [dbo].[tb_EventLog] as s 
CROSS APPLY s.otherData.nodes('/otherData/timeRecord') as m(c)

Comment: thanks so much...this worked very well. Can you elaborate the code for me and others like me!!